# Having issues implementing date range filter in react native iOS/Android

Tags: javascript, react-native

[Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@anushkas/bc42a4) I am trying to filter a bar chart according to dates I select from a daterange picker.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import DatePicker from 'react-native-datepicker';
import { LineChart, BarChart } from 'react-native-chart-kit';

const initialData = [12, 19, 12, 25];
const initialLevelsArr = ['09-10-2020', '10-10-2020', '11-10-2020', '12-10-2020'];
const initialLabels = ['09-10-2020', '10-10-2020', '11-10-2020', '12-10-2020'];
const initialstartDate = '09-10-2020';
const initialendDate = '09-10-2020';

const App = () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(initialstartDate);
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(initialendDate);
  const [labels, setLabels] = useState(initialLabels);
  const [datas, setDatas] = useState(initialData);
  const handlestartChange = (date) => {
    /*setStartDate(date);*/
    const newStartDate = date.toString();
    const slicedStartDate = newStartDate;
    setStartDate(slicedStartDate);
  };
  console.log(startDate);
  const handleendChange = (date) => {
    /*setEndDate(date);*/
    const newEndDate = date.toString();
    const slicedEndDate = newEndDate;
    setEndDate(slicedEndDate);
  };
  console.log(endDate);
  const applyDateFilter = () => {
    console.log(startDate);
    console.log(endDate);
    const newLabels = initialLevelsArr.slice(toString(startDate), toString(endDate) + 1);
    const newDatas = initialData.slice(toString(startDate), toString(endDate) + 1);

    setLabels(newLabels);
    setDatas(newDatas);
  };
  const dataset = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [
      {
        data: datas,
        colors: [(opacity = 1) => `red`, (opacity = 1) => `blue`, (opacity = 1) => `yellow`, (opacity = 1) => `green`],
      },
    ],
  };
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button onPress={() => applyDateFilter()} title="Apply DateFilter" color="#841584" />
        <DatePicker
          style={styles.datePickerStyle}
          date={startDate} // Initial date from state
          mode="date" // The enum of date, datetime and time
          placeholder="select date"
          format="DD-MM-YYYY"
          minDate="09-10-2020"
          maxDate="12-10-2020"
          confirmBtnText="Confirm"
          cancelBtnText="Cancel"
          customStyles={{
            dateIcon: {
              //display: 'none',
              position: 'absolute',
              left: 0,
              top: 4,
              marginLeft: 0,
            },
            dateInput: {
              marginLeft: 36,
            },
          }}
          onDateChange={handlestartChange}
        />
        <DatePicker
          style={styles.datePickerStyle}
          date={endDate} // Initial date from state
          mode="date" // The enum of date, datetime and time
          placeholder="select date"
          format="DD-MM-YYYY"
          minDate="09-10-2020"
          maxDate="12-10-2020"
          confirmBtnText="Confirm"
          cancelBtnText="Cancel"
          customStyles={{
            dateIcon: {
              //display: 'none',
              position: 'absolute',
              left: 0,
              top: 4,
              marginLeft: 0,
            },
            dateInput: {
              marginLeft: 36,
            },
          }}
          onDateChange={handleendChange}
        />
        <BarChart
          data={dataset}
          width={400}
          height={220}
          withCustomBarColorFromData={true}
          flatColor={true}
          fromZero={true}
          chartConfig={{
            backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
            backgroundGradientFrom: '#ffffff',
            backgroundGradientTo: '#ffffff',
            data: dataset.datasets,
            color: (opacity = 1) => '#fff',
            labelColor: () => '#6a6a6a',
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    padding: 20,
  },
  datePickerStyle: {
    width: 200,
    marginTop: 20,
  },
});
```

Currently, the bar chart looks like this-
[image]
However, upon date selection, the bar chart completely goes blank and there's nothing to be seen-
[image]
I am not sure why the dates filter won't apply here. It might have to do something with how the `applyDateFilter` function is written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change as following.

```
const handlestartChange = (date) => {
  setStartDate(date);
};
const handleendChange = (date) => {
  setEndDate(date);
};
const applyDateFilter = () => {
  const newLabels = [],
    newDatas = [];
  initialLevelsArr.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (item >= startDate && item <= endDate) {
      newLabels.push(item);
      newDatas.push(initialData[index]);
    }
  });
  setLabels(newLabels);
  setDatas(newDatas);
};
```